# У меня всё не работает или у меня ничего не работает

Tags: грамотная-речь

Бывает, пользователи обращаются с просьбой починить что-либо в компьютере, потому что оно сломалось, и диалог часто начинают с фразы:

> У меня **всё** не работает!!

или

> У меня **ничего** не работает!!

Как правильно с точки зрения русского языка или оба варианта допустимы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разбора на эту тему я не нашла, поэтому могу высказать свое мнение.

Мне кажется, что выбор варианта **зависит от ситуации**, и семантика для местоимений ***всё*** и ***ничего*** может быть разной.

1) *Что у вас не работает? — У меня **всё не работает**! — Ну хотя бы что-то работает? — Нет, **ничего не работает**!*

Как мы видим, на разные вопросы даются разные ответы.

2) *Ты всю группу пригласил? — Да, но **все не придут**. Некоторые уже разъехались по домам.*

В данном случае верен только выбранный вариант, местоимение ***никто*** не подходит.

В подобных ситуациях при использовании местоимений ***всё, все*** делается **противопоставление части и целого**: *все не придут, а придут только некоторые. Всё сломалось, а не что-то одно.*